# Understanding AWS IoT from an Application perspective

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I understand Aws IoT from a device perspective that it should connect with a certificate and sync with its shadow and push messages to topics. But I struggle to understand from the perspective of a Web App or a Mobile App. My basic questions are,

1. How to register an Application with AWS IoT?
2. What is the Authentication and Authorization mechanism for Applications?
3. How to grant an App access to a set of devices?
4. How can the App listen to messages from devices of interest?
5. How can the App send a command to device? I understand this is by
   updating Device's shadow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you want to connect any application (Mobile, Web,...) to any AWS Services, you should consider two things. First, using AWS SDKs which you can find them [here](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/?nc1=h_ls). Second, the application should have correct Authentication and Authorization attached to a user/group defined in IAM or Cognito.
In regards to your questions:

1. For registering an application in AWS IoT, first it should be defined as an IoT thing and with correct policies, it can publish/subscribe to topics. Consider that, you should put certificates into the device. For connecting to AWS IoT services you can use AWS IoT SDKs, more information can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdks.html).

   2 & 3. It depends on your project. You can define your application to have access to a specific thing in AWS IoT or you can define it to access all things in AWS IoT service (using IAM, Cognito or Temporary Security Credentials). You should consider correct policies for your application. You can find more information about authentication and authorization for AWS IoT [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-security-identity.html).
2. AWS IoT has MQTT broker which handles the communication between entities that publish or subscribe to a topics. So if the application wants to get data from specific device, it should subscribe to the topic that things publish to.
3. It can be done by publishing data to a topic which thing has subscribed to.

Thing shadow is actually the digital twin of actual thing so it should contains information which is related to the thing such as available resources, etc.

Comment: Thank you. To confirm #1, is it the expectation that a Web/Mobile App be registered as a "IoT Thing", inorder to publish or subscribe to other things, which are real devices ?

Comment: For publishing/subscribing to a topic in AWS IoT through web/mobile app you have three choices, either defining the app as an IoT device or the app act some how a AWS user which means that you can define a user in IAM and use its credentials to publish/subscribe to a topic (Not recommended). The third one is using Temporary Security Credentials, more information about it can be found  [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html).